# Access to created view from index of list

Tags: sharepoint-online

I created normal sharepoint online list and I created another View to that list, my question is, how can I access to my created View from Index one. For example, to access to create View I just pick "New Element", to access to Edit View just clic on Edit icon:

[image]

But how can I access to view I just created? Regards

[image]

Comment: You should see a link to the view you created beside the default view. Add a full screenshot of what you see now.

Comment: I added screenshot of list. @jpollar

Comment: I realized what you did wrong just now. You didn't create a new view. The icon you reference above allows you to edit an existing list item.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to create a custom view. Let me know if you have any questions.

[Create a custom list view in SharePoint Online](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-custom-list-view-in-sharepoint-online-d51d74b4-573d-4cf3-a872-fdb8ab2b48a6)

> 1. In the app launcher, click SharePoint, locate and go to the site, and then open the list. If you can’t find the list, click Settings,
>      click Site Contents, and then open the list.
> 2. Do one of the following: Create a new view from scratch
>
> a.In the Command bar, click View options, and then click Manage
>   views. If View options is not visible, make sure you are not editing
>   the list or have not selected one or more items. Also, you may not
>   have permission. In that case, contact the Office 365 admin or the
>   site or list owners.
>
> b. Go to step 3.
>
> Create a new view based on the current view and view type
>
> c. In the Command bar, click View options.
>
> If View options is not visible, make sure you are not editing the list
>   or have not selected one or more items. Also, you may not have
>   permission. In that case, contact the Office 365 admin or the site or
>   list owners.
>
> d. Click Save.
>
> e. Enter the new name, and then click OK.
>
> f. Click View options again, and then click the name of the view you
>   just created.
>
> g. At the bottom of the Settings page, under Views, click the name of
>   the view you just created.
>
> h. Go to step 6.
>
> 3. At the bottom of the Settings page, click Create view.
> 4. On the View Type page, choose a view type, which opens the Create View page for that view type. The most common view types are Standard
>      View and Datasheet view. By default, you can only edit one item at a
>      time in Standard View but you can edit many items at once in Datasheet
>      view. However, you can temporarily change Standard view to Datasheet
>      View by using Quick edit.
>
> Important:  Once you choose a view type, you cannot change it, but you
>   can create another view with a different view type. For more
>   information, see View types you can choose.
>
> 5. In the View Name box, type the name for your view.
> 6. Select Make this the default view if you want to make this the default view for the list. Only a public view can be the default view.
> 7. In the Audience section, under View Audience, select Create a Personal view or Create a Public view. Create a personal view when you
>      want a view just for yourself. Create a public view when you want
>      everyone who uses the list to see it.
>
> Note:  If Create a Public View is disabled, you don’t have Design
>   permission level or higher.
>
> 8. In the Columns section, select the columns that you want in the view and clear the columns that you don’t want to appear. Next to the
>      column numbers, select the order that you want to columns to appear in
>      the view.
> 9. Change other settings for your view, such as Sort and Filter, and then click OK at the bottom of the page. For more information, see
>      Edit a list view in SharePoint Online.